# Django Celery shared_task singleton pattern

Tags: django, celery

I have a Django based site that has several background processes that are executed in Celery workers. I have one particular task that can run for a few seconds with several read/writes to the database that are subject to a race condition if a second task tries to access the same rows.

I'm trying to prevent this by ensuring the task is only ever running on a single worker at a time but I'm running into issues getting this to work correctly. I've used this [Celery Task Cookbook Recipe](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) as inspiration, trying to make my own version that works for my scenario of ensuring that this specific task is only running on one worker at a time, but it still seems to be possible to encounter situations where it's executed across more than one worker.

So far, in `tasks.py` I have:

```
class LockedTaskInProgress(Exception):
    """The locked task is already in progress"""
    silent_variable_failure = True


@shared_task(autoretry_for=[LockedTaskInProgress], default_retry_delay=30)
def create_or_update_payments(things=None):
    """
    This takes a list of `things` that we want to process payments on. It will
    read the thing's status, then apply calculations to make one or more payments
    for various users that are owed money for the thing.

    `things` - The list of things we need to process payments on.
    """
    lock = cache.get('create_or_update_payments')  # Using Redis as our cache backend

    if not lock:
        logger.debug('Starting create/update payments processing. Locking task.')
        cache.set('create_or_update_payments', 'LOCKED')
        real_create_or_update_payments(things)  # Long running function w/ lots of DB read/writes
        cache.delete('create_or_update_payments')
        logger.debug('Completed create/update payments processing. Lock removed.')
    else:
        logger.debug('Unable to process create/update payments at this time. Lock detected.')
        raise LockedTaskInProgress
```

The above seems to *almost* work but there still looks to be a possible race condition between the `cache.get` and `cache.set` that has shown up in my testing.

I'd love to get suggestions on how to improve this to make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've found a way of doing this, inspired by an older version of the Celery Task Cookbook Recipe I was using earlier.

Here's my implementation:

```
class LockedTaskInProgress(Exception):
    """The locked task is already in progress"""
    silent_variable_failure = True


@shared_task(autoretry_for=[LockedTaskInProgress], default_retry_delay=30)
def create_or_update_payments(things=None):
    """
    This takes a list of `things` that we want to process payments on. It will
    read the thing's status, then apply calculations to make one or more payments
    for various users that are owed money for the thing.

    `things` - The list of things we need to process payments on.
    """
    LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 5  # 5 Mins
    lock_id = 'create_or_update_payments'

    acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_id, 'LOCKED', LOCK_EXPIRE)
    release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_id)

    if acquire_lock():
        try:
            logger.debug('Starting create/update payments processing. Locking task.')
            real_create_or_update_payments(things)  # Long running function w/ lots of DB read/writes
        finally:
            release_lock()
            logger.debug('Completed create/update payments processing. Lock removed.')
    else:
        logger.debug('Unable to process create/update payments at this time. Lock detected.')
        raise LockedTaskInProgress
```

It's very possible that there's a better way of doing this but this seems to work in my tests.